# cannot reach push notification over first responder keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios

Ok 
On first run I ask for the mobile phone number in an alertview. This is using - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField to validate the phone number.

Now I also have push notifications.

The trouble is when the app is first installed the alertview shows and the keyboard shows but the "Do you want to enable push notifications" alert also shows.  So whats the problem?  Well the alert shows then over the alert the push notification shows blocking the input box.  Then the keyboard shows blocking the "Yes/No" buttons of the push notification.

Therefor I cannot dismiss or answer either alert!  So my first thought is to comment out [passwordField becomeFirstResponder]; for the phone number alert and the keyboard can be dismissed but then my validation never gets called. :(

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: your probably going to need to move your alert box, maybe make a load screen come up first.  you cannot stop the push notification box from coming up so your only option is to change when your alert box comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delay your register for push notifications code until after your UI is done.